# fa fa-cube without transparent background

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

i was wondering if I can change the "fa fa-cube" so the background is not transparent. I want to use it on top of a playingcard-background and as you can see below, it doesn't look that great like this...

The best would be a white or light-blue fill.

Maybe i can put another cube behind it? But i am really a beginner.

```css
.deck {
    border: 2px dashed #080808;
    width: 160px;
    height: 120px;
    
}

    .deck .card {
        justify-content: space-around;
        font-size: 50px;
        color: #0023F5;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        transform-origin: center;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border: 5px solid black;
        height: 116px;
        background-color: #e5e5f7;
        opacity: 0.8;
        background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #F74141 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(225deg, #F74141 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(45deg, #F74141 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(315deg, #F74141 25%, #e5e5f7 25%);
        background-position: 10px 0, 10px 0, 0 0, 0 0;
        background-size: 10px 10px;
        background-repeat: repeat;
    }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="deck">
  <div class="card">
    <i class="drawing fa fa-cube"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Cube]

PS: i tried aria-hidden="true" but didn't really know what this does.

Comment: Add css `.drawing:before {background: white;}`

Comment: I get a whole white square when i do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the most *elegant* solution but it works. Basically, I layered in copies of the icon (as filler) and used a couple of different clip-paths to render the white background where the transparent parts are, then put everything in a container and used z-index to push the white parts behind the actual blue icon so the background fillers wouldn't overlap the actual blue icon. You can use the container for positioning etc.

```css
.deck {
  border: 2px dashed #080808;
  width: 160px;
  height: 120px;
}

.deck .card {
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #0023F5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  height: 116px;
  background-color: #e5e5f7;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #F74141 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(225deg, #F74141 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(45deg, #F74141 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(315deg, #F74141 25%, #e5e5f7 25%);
  background-position: 10px 0, 10px 0, 0 0, 0 0;
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.faContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.fa-cube {
  z-index: 1;
}

.fa-cubeBGTop {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: white;
  clip-path: polygon(7% 28%, 47% 14%, 86% 29%, 46% 44%);
}

.fa-cubeBGSide {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: white;
  clip-path: polygon(43% 50%, 85% 30%, 90% 78%, 38% 95%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="deck">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="faContainer">
      <i class="drawing fa fa-cube"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-cube fa-cubeBGTop"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-cube fa-cubeBGSide"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```